# Specify spacing

Tags: spacing

I am having some trouble specifying **exactly** the space between two lines.

I don't want to apply this to the whole document, but only to certain spots.

Here is one case:

[image]

This should be 0.20in.

Comment: Use the optional argument to \\ to add additional space between the lines, e.g.\\[10pt].

Comment: There is also the question of whether you want baseline-to-baseline or bottom-to-top spacing.  Sometimes the best solution is to use a strut (e.g. `\rule{0pt}{.2in}`)

Comment: \\\[10pt] is not applied to lines (I don't know why).
I tried using \rule, but it does not work as I want.